# Extract date and remove characters which don't need

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column by extracting date information from text. I found that date is at the end of each row, within the last two round brackets.

```
 Text

    "«A mio avviso, e credo non solo mio, (17-11-2020 12:42:05)"
     "Roma, 17 nov – Dalle elezioni, non è facile (…)\n (17-11-2020 12:42:04)"
     'Decine di avvocati del libero foro di tutte le regioni  ... (17-11-2020 12:41:08)'
     "Ci sono riusciti: vi stanno facendo odiare l'un l'altro (17-11-2020 12:41:01)"
     'Luciano ,\xa0 coreografo, esprime la sua opinione e il mondo de... (17-11-2020 12:40:01)'
```

To extract the datetime, I did as follows:

```
df['Date'] = df['Text'].str.extract('(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)$)')
```

This works fine overall, but there are a few cases that I would like to remove as well, not included in the previous code.
For example:

```
0                17-11-2020 12:42:05
1                17-11-2020 12:42:04
2                17-11-2020 12:41:08
3        video) (17-11-2020 12:41:01 # <- here the wrong extraction
4                17-11-2020 12:40:01
                    ...             
20084            07-02-2020 12:47:11
```

The text for that row is the following:

```
"Ci sono riusciti: vi stanno facendo odiare l'un l'altro. (video) (17-11-2020 12:41:01)"
```

I extracted only content within the last parenthesis, I would be able to get what I want, i..e. 17-11-2020 12:41:01.

Do you know how can I get this?
Thanks

Comment: `(\((?:.(?!\())+$)` is closer to what you are looking for

Comment: Hi Vivek, could you please check the brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
df['Text'].str.extract(r'(?:(\()(?!.*\1))(.*)(?:(\))(?!.*\1))').iloc[:,1]
```

**Output**

```
0    17-11-2020 12:42:05
1    17-11-2020 12:42:04
2    17-11-2020 12:41:08
3    17-11-2020 12:41:01
4    17-11-2020 12:40:01
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run through it twice. Extract and replace

```
df['Date'] = df['Text'].str.extract('(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)$)').replace(regex='[a-z]+\)\s\(',value='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
df['Date'] = df['Text'].str.extract('\(([^()]*)\)$')
```